# PostgreSQL time complexity of WHERE and ORDER BY clause

Tags: postgresql

Assume we are running the following query on a PostgteSQL table *table1* with column *col1* indexed via b-tree...

`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE col1='foo' ORDER BY col2;`

Would the time complexity of the query be equal to...

`O(log(n) + m*log(m))`

given *n* is the number of rows in *table1* and *m* is the number of rows satisfying the where clause?

Comment: fully indexed on col1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming an O(n log n) sorting algorithm is used...

If it does use the index, then yes, it's O(log n) to search the B-Tree and O(m log m) to order the rows.

However, databases are a case where the constants cannot be ignored. The constant on an index lookup is relatively high compared to a sequential scan. If most of the table matches `col1='foo'`, Postgres might decide a full table scan, O(n), is faster than the index because of its lower constant. Then it's O(n + m log m).

In addition, the size of m will affect whether a file sort or in-memory sort can be used drastically effecting efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

If the index is used for the condition, then the complexity would be

```
O(log(n) + m * log(m))
```

`log(n)` is for finding the first matching row, and `m * log(m)` is for sorting. There is an additional term `m` for reading `m` rows from the index, but `m < m * log(m)`.

If you have an index on `(col1,col2)`, you would get away without additional sorting, and the complexity would be reduced to

```
O(log(n) + m)
```